# Create a Part directly from a MEF catalog?

Tags: .net, mef

Is there a way in MEF 4.0 to get create a part directly from a catalog?  I know that there was a container in the previous version, but that seems to have been abstracted away.

**Edits:**

To clarify, I have an external package download module.  A package is my terminology for a XAP external to my main application which I use a `DeploymentCatalog` to download.  When the asynchronous call returns the module then returns an `IPackage` instance which contains metadata and initialization entry points for the package.  I want to do this for convenience.  If I use an include-many, it is a little two decoupled in this one spot.

Other parts of the application (i.e. the navigation module) do use includes.

Comment: What version of .Net are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MEF shipped for the first time in dotnet 4.0, so 
there is no "previous version" (unless you count the previews on codeplex).

Dotnet 4.0 definitely has a [CompositionContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.compositioncontainer.aspx) class. Perhaps you are confused because you have this in your code:

```
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
```

but CompositionContainer is actually in `System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting`? Or maybe you forgot to add a reference to System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll?

Comment: By previous version, I mean there used to be another way of initialization before the `CompositionHost.Initialize`  A lot of the early screen casts (including those by Mike Tulty) used a different way to initialize the catalogs.